# Block users from multi-login on website

Tags: ajax, authentication, coldfusion, cfml

I want to block users from accessing my ColdFusion application more than once at the same time.

I have a SQL table with dtLogin, dtLogLastUpdate, ip and isLogged.

The logic is:

Session timeout is 1h.

When user logs in,

- set dtLogin = datestamp now
- dtLogLastUpdate = datestamp now
- ip = user-ip
- isLogged = 1

I am using an AJAX call to update `dtLogLastUpdate` every 1 minute.

When I get a log in request for the user, only allow it if `isLogged` is 0 OR  `dtLogLastUpdate` is more than my session timeout in the past.

How do I manage when users close their browser but don't log out before? Will they need to wait until the session timeout?

Comment: I would consider using onSessionEnd to log people out auomatically.  This would handle people who close their browsers.  Also if a browser is closed, the DtLogLastUpdated would be x number of minutes old.  If the browser was open and doing the ajax call, the session would stay active and keep the dtLogLastUpdated up to date.  You may also want to search for "coldfusion who's online" applications.  there is an old one out there that may provide code samples.

Comment: Maybe you could log out `old user` and allow `new user` to login.

Comment: can't you compare `dtLogLastUpdate` to the current time? If it hasn't pinged in over a minute I would think you can assume they closed their tab

Comment: You could check the value of `dtLogLastUpdate` being more than 1 minute in the past. Since you are updating it every 1 minute if it has not been updated you can assume they are gone. Not sure how much I would trust that though???  I don't trust any data coming from the client. In my apps I typically rely on the session timeout as you mentioned.  NOTE: if the user closes their browser (all instances) and opens a new one, they will get a new session as far as ColdFusion is concerned.

Comment: http://www.justskins.com/forums/whos-online-116495.html you may be able to borrow some code from this example of a who's online routine.  It looks pretty good.

Comment: @Miguel-F, there is a downside to ending the session if the dtLogLastUpdate is more than a minute old.  If the user goes to another page for about 10 minutes or so, and comes back before his hour is up, his session should still be open.  Closing it based on the age of the dtLogLastUpdate field would prevent that.

Answer (score 2):

I would create an application variable called currentUsers.

You can use an array or a list, I think array functions are faster but depending on your version of ColdFusion searching an array can be a pain. I'll use list functions for simplicity.

When a user tries to log in, check the list for the user name.  If it isn't there, add the user name to the list and allow them to log in.  If the username exists, send them to some default "too bad, so sad" landing page.

```
<cfif listFindNoCase(application.currentUsers, form.userName)> 
    <cflocation url = "shameOnYou.cfm">
<cfelse>
    <cfset listAppend(application.currentUsers, form.userName)>
    <cfset session.whatever>
</cfif>
```

In your application.cfc, use onSessionEnd to remove the user name from the list.

```
<cffunction onSessionEnd...>
    <cfset listDeleteAt(application.currentUsers,listFind(application.currentUsers, session.userName))>
</cffunction>
```

The benefit of this is you don't need to use AJAX to update the log file every 60 seconds, reducing background processes.

Comment: You might mention that the downside to this is that the user will need to wait until the session expires (1 hour in the OP's case) before they can log in again.  When they don't logout properly.

Comment: If they close their existing browser (all of them) and open a new one.  I also mentioned that in my comment above.  Is that what you are referring too?

Comment: He could always use JavaScript's `beforeunload` too.  I think support for it is pretty wide.